# Scrolling toolbar in fragments android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have bottom navigation view consist of three fragments in my app.
I have two fragments consist of recycler view and third is simple profile fragment.I am using scrolling toolbar in my activity_main file but it is scrolling toolbar in all the three fragments.I don't want scrolling toolbar in third fragment.

This is my code below:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/chooseLocation"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:hint="Search here"
        android:textColorHint="#9e9e9e"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:background="@drawable/search_edit_text"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_check"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_check"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Some please let me know how can I achieve desired layout.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: You don't have layout files for 3 fragments separately?

Comment: I have them too. They are linked with bottom navigation bar.

Comment: attach fragment files or at least images showing the issue.

Comment: Move the collapsing toolbar to those two fragments then and leave the other one as your profile..